# Initial value producing an error in a dynamic display

Tags: plotting

I have

```
DynamicModule[{f, surf},
 f[x_, y_] = x^2 y + 3 x y^4;
 surf = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> 3,
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6],
   ClippingStyle -> None];
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   surf,
   ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[2 t], Cos[t], f[Sin[2 t], Cos[t]]}, {t, 0, 
     final},
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
   ], {{final, 0.1}, 0, 2 Pi}
  ]
 ]
```

which produces this image

[image]

However, when I move the slider to zero, I get this image.

[image]

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I only get it if `final` is allowed to become `0`, then you get a host of messages along with `ParametricPlot3D` returning unevaluated. But, changing the range to `{{final, 0.1}, 0.1, 2 Pi}` works just fine for me.

Comment: Works fine for me (v. 10.1, Mac OS X) except at *final -> 0*.  Thus change the range to `{0.001, 2 Pi}` or the plot `{t, -0.001, final}`.

Comment: There are some great and wonderful fixes here, but I am also wondering why it happens.

Comment: Doesn't the error message make clear what the problem is? (Try `ParametricPlot3D[{t, t, t}, {t, 0, 0}]` if the ``FE`final$$1819`` is confusing you; or execute ``FE`final$$1819`` or whatever the current varialble is.  Note that ``FE`final$$1819`` is the actual variable instance created by the Front End for you variable `final`.)  I've always felt this was a wrong decision by Wolfram, and instead of an unevaluated command, one should get an empty plot.  Your use-case, which I've encountered many times, illustrates why.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Thanks for a nice clear explanation. I tried both of your suggestions and it made things clear.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[2 t], Cos[t], f[Sin[2 t], Cos[t]]}, {t, 0, final}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}]
```

with

```
If[final > 0, 
  ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[2 t], Cos[t], f[Sin[2 t], Cos[t]]}, {t, 0, final}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}], 
  {}]]
```

#### Edit

Full code with image at `final = 0`

```
DynamicModule[{f, surf},
  f[x_, y_] = x^2 y + 3 x y^4;
  surf = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    PlotRange -> 3, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6], 
    ClippingStyle -> None];
  Manipulate[
    Show[
      surf,
      If[final > 0, 
        ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[2 t], Cos[t], f[Sin[2 t], Cos[t]]}, {t, 0, final}, 
          PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}], 
        {}]],
    {final, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

Another fix, besides excluding the offending value from the range is to suppress the error:

```
 Quiet@Check[
     ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[2 t], Cos[t], f[Sin[2 t], Cos[t]]}, {t, 0, 
           final}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}], {}]
```

Edit: the full working code:

```
 DynamicModule[{f, surf}, f[x_, y_] = x^2 y + 3 x y^4;
   surf = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> 3, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.6], ClippingStyle -> None];
     Manipulate[
      Show[surf, 
    Quiet@Check[
      ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[2 t], Cos[t], f[Sin[2 t], Cos[t]]}, 
        {t, 0,final}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue}], {}]],
             {{final, 0.1}, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for (the now retracted) down vote. Without full code, didn't test and misread your original version.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `$MachineEpsilon` to the lower bound of the `final` range.

```
{{final, 0.1}, 0 + $MachineEpsilon, 2 Pi}
```

This will allow final to go as close to zero as possible, from above, without equalling zero; the supremum of `final > 0`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice idea. Thanks.